# Measure thermal conductivity without temperature gradient

Tags: thermal-conductivity

Is there any way to measure thermal conductivity without temperature gradient? We are trying to measure the thermal conductivity with X-ray scattering. However, limited by the instrumentation, we can only heat the entire material to a uniform temperature at a steady-state, but we can do it at many different temperatures, for example, 300, 400, 500K. Is there any way to measure the thermal conductivity in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not easily. In principle I think if you could approximate the geometry of the part as a semi-infinite slab or sphere or something, you could subject it to a certain condition and monitor the temp vs time, and compare it to a transient heat conduction solution that depends on the Fourier number, and back out the conductivity from that. Extremely roundabout method of very dubious accuracy

My advice for a practical need is, get more instrumentation.

I'd love to hear more about the application though.